# CMS not taking email while creating new customer

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, email

I am creating different clients on the CMS part of Magento 1.9

There is only 1 email address that is not recording, everytime I try to create a new client with the email address. It just goes back to the Manage Customers page, without throwing any error.

Is only one specific email address.

Should I just give it some time and come back later. Like I said it does not show any error message at all.

Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saved the customer on CMS with a different email address. Went directly into the database and modify the customer from there. Resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I would be trying to identify the one thing that's different about that particular email address.

The only thing I can think of is maybe it contains special characters like slashes or quotes or apostrophes or something...?

Comment: Everything on the email address is similar to the other ones. They are all from the same company. I created the customer with a different email address (which is a wrong address) and I am thinking of maybe going directly to the db and find that table and try to change the email address from there.